# Mental Poker Toolkit

Tags: cryptography, distributed, poker

Can anyone suggest a toolkit or framework (or maybe an idea) that can be useful to implement secure and cheat-resistant online poker (texas hold'em) client without trusted third party server?

Comment: If you want some ideas on how to generate cheat-resistant random numbers in a distributed way, ask at [crypto.SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/). Though have a look at [How to fairly select a random number for a game without trusting a third party?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/767/how-to-fairly-select-a-random-number-for-a-game-without-trusting-a-third-party) first. (I don't know of any libraries/toolkits/frameworks implementing this, though.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you're asking about is called [mental poker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mental_poker), described in [this fascinating paper](http://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/ShamirRivestAdleman-MentalPoker.pdf)(PDF) by cryptographic greats Adi Shamir, Ron Rivest, and Leonard Adleman. Per their summary of results:

> We present two solutions to the problem of playing Mental Poker:
>
> 1. A rigorous proof that it is theoretically impossible to deal the
>      cards in a way which simultaneously ensures that the two hands are
>      disjoint and neither player has any knowledge of the other player's
>      hand (other than that the opponent's hand is disjoint from his).
> 2. An elegant protocol for dealing the cards that permits one to play
>      a fair game of Mental Poker as desired.
>
> The blatant contradiction between our two results is not due to any
>   tricks or faults in either result. In fact, we will leave to the
>   reader the enjoyable task of puzzling out the differences in the
>   underlying assumptions that account for our seemingly contradictory
>   results.

Note that their result only applies to two player games of poker. The paper [Mental poker with three or more players](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=5517635108370873150&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5) extends this result to multiple players.

In short, can it be done? Probably, yes. Is it practical? Almost certainly not. You should establish or find a trusted third party instead.

Comment: why is it not practical?

Comment: @menzoic Read the papers and find out. :)

Answer (score 3):

LibTMCG is such a Frameworks http://libtmcg.nongnu.org